# Shitai desu and shimasu

Tags: word-choice

what is the difference between these two sentences:

1. Nanika shitaidesuka/ Nanika shitai n desuka
2. Nani o shimasuka.

   ```
            Thanks
   ```

Comment: The shimasu/shitai change is a the "desire" verb formation. You can find it described in nearly every textbook or online guide to Japanese. Seriously consider one of the [online courses](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/763#763) or at least [textbooks](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/766#766) from our resources list.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the "tai" form of a verb, it expresses the desire to do something.

何{なに}かしたいですか。

Nanika shitai desuka

> Do you want to do something?

何{なに}をしますか。

Nani o shimasuka

> What (you/we) (do/will do)?

Answer (score 0):

〜たい (…tai) means **want**. It expresses desire.

> Nanika shitaidesuka/ Nanika shitai n desuka

These means "Do you want to do something?" Even if the sentence has `n` in between shitai and desuka, its meaning are *changeless*.

> nani o shimasuka

This means "what you do?" That is why it does not has `...tai`, it does not express desire.